# Is there a different Web Browser component that I can use that is NOT IE based for VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control

I'm working on a project that requires the display of a web page and the use of components in that webpage to display information on a second monitor. Internet Explorer is the bane of my existence since I am developing on Windows 7 and most of my employers clients still use XP, hence IE8. Windows 7 doesn't support IE8 without jumping through a bunch of hoops and it's being a monstrous pain in the backside. Is there ANY Web Browser component out there that uses something other than Internet Explorer?

Comment: Windows 7 *ships* with IE8, so I should hope it's supported!

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebKit.Net http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/ that is a .NET wrapper over the webkit browser.

Comment: Which is one of many. Looking for either chrome or webkit with "managed wrapper" returns many results.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Awesomium .NET](http://awesomium.codeplex.com/) a C# wrapper for the Chromium toolkit. It's very powerful in that you can actually get the raw pixel data for the rendered webpage or you can just use one of the pre-built controls to embed in your application.